# Creating a Flatlist for a list of components in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created a component which itself is composed of several components.Now all these components will get data dynamically and i need to repeat this main component N no of times.Here is the screenshot of the component to be repeated.[image: Screenshot of Data to repeat]

The colored panel will have some data and the heading and all text will be updated dynamically.

Here is the code which i have written so far

```
     //FirstScreen.js
import React from 'react';

    import { Text, StyleSheet, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
    import Icon  from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
    import SquareCircle from './Square_circle_Button'
    import CirclePlus from './circle_plus'
    import DateComponent from './DateComponent'
    import LibraryComponent from './LibraryComponent'

        class FirstScreen extends React.Component
        {
          constructor(props) 
          {
            super(props);
          }

          render() {
            return <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}>
            <DateComponent DateDisplay={this.props.DDate}/>
                <View style={{ flex: 4, flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
                <LibraryComponent Heading={this.props.send_heading} DisplayData={this.props.DData}/>
                </View>
              </View>;
          }
        }

    //LibraryComponent.js
import React from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";

export default class LibraryComponent extends React.Component
{
    render(){
        return <View style={{ flex: 4, flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
              <Text>{this.props.Heading}</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
              <Text>{this.props.DisplayData}</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{ flex: 4, flexDirection: "row", alignContent: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
              <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: "powderblue" }} />
              <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: "skyblue" }} />
              <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: "steelblue" }} />
              <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: "gray" }} />
            </View>
          </View>;
    }
}

//DateComponent.js

import React from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";

export default class DateComponent extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return(
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
  <Text>{this.props.DateDisplay}</Text>
        </View>);
    }

}

//TimeScroll.js

import React from 'react'
import {FlatList,View} from 'react-native'
import FirstScreen from './FirstScreen'
import CirclePlus from './circle_plus'
import AddCircle from './Square_circle_Button'


export default class Timeline extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return(
            <FlatList style={{flex:1}}>
                data={[
                    {key:"20 Mar 2018"},
                ]}
                renderItem={({item}) =><View style={{flex:1}}>
                <FirstScreen send_heading={item.key} DData={item.key} DDate={item.key}/>
                </View>}
                <CirclePlus/>
                <AddCircle/>
                </FlatList>
        );
    }
}
```

If requested,Let me know how should i modify the structure to accomplish this task properly.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to structure your prop data to be an array of objects where each object has the data for each color palette:

```
//FirstScreen.js
import React from 'react';

import { Text, StyleSheet, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import Icon  from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import SquareCircle from './Square_circle_Button'
import CirclePlus from './circle_plus'
import DateComponent from './DateComponent'
import LibraryComponent from './LibraryComponent'

class FirstScreen extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    renderColorPalettes = () => {
        const { colorData } = this.props;

        return colorData.map( palette => {
            return <LibraryComponent Heading={palette.heading} DisplayData={palette.data}/>
        });
    };

    render() {
        const colors = renderColorPalettes();
        return <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}>
            <DateComponent DateDisplay={this.props.DDate}/>
            <View style={{ flex: 4, flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
                {colors}
            </View>
        </View>;
    }
}
```